# c++ mysqlpp::storequeryresult and std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

i´d like to know if there is a quicker way to copy my data from a mysqlpp::storequeryresult to a std::vector.

My example is as follows:
I store my Query Result with query.store() in StoreQueryResult and my result is e.g. a table with one column with doubles in it. Now I want to copy those doubles into a std::vector. The way I´m doing it right now is to access every single double with the [][] operator and copy it to my vector in a for-loop.

This works but it is very time consuming since i´m copying like 277000 double in a loop. Is there a way to just copy the column to my vector? The thing is my other functions use std::vectors in their parameterlists. Alternatively i could change my functions to call a StoreQueryResult i guess, but i´d prefere a std::vector.

Here is my simplified code:

```
void foo()
{
   vector<double> vec;
   mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult sqr;
   Query query;
   query << "SELECT * FROM tablename";
   sqr = query.store();
   vec.reserve(sqr.num_rows());
   vec.resize(sqr.size());
      for(int i=0; i != vec.size(); i++)
      {
       vec[i] = sqr[i]["my_column"]; 
      }
}
```

I want something like:

```
vec = sqr["my_column"]  // when my_column is a field with doubles
```

Thx in advance.

Martin

Comment: Please consider adding some example code what you're doing.

Comment: You're reserving that target vector to a size equivalent to the row count of your SQR before the copy, right ? (*Post the code*).

Comment: Right the vector is the same size as the number of rows of the StoreQueryResult.

Comment: @Martin that wasn't what I asked. I asked if the space was reserved *before* the copy, and the posted code update isn't much help, as neither I nor the compiler read `...` very well in the context you provided it.  That `...` had better do more than just pass the time or that follow up for-loop will copy absolutely nothing, as `vec` has zero-size. *Post **real** code please.*, ideally from inception of query execution to *completed* desired vector. And see LRO's answer below.

Comment: I´ll try what LRO suggested. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, if you need to copy then you need to copy, and whether you write the loop yourself or get a library function to do it isn't particularly relevant.

What you *can* do is pre-`reserve` enough space in the destination vector to avoid repeated re-allocations and copies:

```
vec.reserve(sqr.num_rows());
```

Comment: I´ll try this. See if it helps. I thought, that initiazing a vector with a size also means allocating the memory for it...
Thx btw.

Comment: @Martin: Yeah, it does - now that I can see that in your code (though I should have guessed from your usage of `vec[i]` rather than `vec.push_back`; whoops), this isn't going to help you!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you wish to create a vector, but then only some values will actually be accessed and used.

In which case we may delay the conversion from `mysqlpp::String` to another datatype:

```
std::vector<mysqlpp::String> data(res.num_rows());
for(size_t i=0, n=res.num_rows(); i<n; ++i)
{
    data[i] = std::move(res[i]["value"]);
}
```

Several things are happening here:

1. We are creating the `vector` that stores `mysqlpp::String`. It is an interesting datatype that can be converted to many others. In your case you were using `operator double () const`.
2. We get the size once, store it, and then use that value. It's the micro-optimisation, together with using `++i` rather than `i++`; they don't add up to many cycles, but should be used, to keep the code in the spirit of optimisation.
3. We move the data, rather than copying it. See [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) if you've not encountered it before.

If then you have something like:

```
double sum = 0.0;
for(size_t i=0, n=data.num_rows(); i<n; i+=2)
{
  sum+=double(data[i]);
}
```

You will only run the conversion routine on ½ of your values.

Of course, if you plan to use the resultant vector several times, you will actually start running the same conversions again and again. So this "optimisation" will actually hurt performance.

Comment: MySQL++ doesn't support moves, does it? What's the purpose of the `std::move` here?